# Windows command to capture what's writing

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there a Windows command that captures what's writing in the console window and write it to a text file?

Comment: are you looking for something like `tee`? There are several implementations for it on Windows, but your question is not quite clear: Windows or DOS? Side-note: it's good style to accept an answer _if it is acceptable_. A look into your profile shows 14 questions with answers but not a single accepted one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, you may want to pipe error output to a file as well. By defualt error output is secondary and isn't logged to the > or >> location. To direct the secondary output to the primary output, add 2>&1 to the end of the line. I.E.:type %ROOTDIR%temp.txt | find /I "test" > %OUT% 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need to redirect the output of one command?  If so, you can use:

```
my_command >output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of any DOS command into a file using > or >>

Exmaple

> dir > files.txt

Sends the output of `dir` into the files.txt overwriting the file if it already exists

> dir >> files.txt

Appends the output of `dir` to files.text

Answer (score 0):

To capture DOS stdout **and** stderr, you need to redirect both to the file that you are going to use for capturing your output.

For example:

C:>dir > dirTest.txt 2>&1

```
|____________||__|
  section 1    section 2
```

Section 1 redirects stdout to the file dirTest.txt, where section 2 redirects stderr to stdout. Microsoft has a good page that explains how you can redirect input and output here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx